# django sortable inlines (not for saving)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is there a django admin option to make inlines sortable by clicking on the table head column (e.g. "name", "price", "venue") like it does for the `changelist_view`. I noticed changing the `Meta.ordering` on the inline model has some inline effects, but i'd really like the user to easily sort by column when viewing large inline sets. Any directions to the obvious would be great, can't be the first one that ran into this.

Answer (score 2):

Alright seems this can only be done customly, by implementing `get_ordering` and add some links and get parameters to the admin html..

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering